# nginx force SSL no-www redirection issues

Tags: linux, redirect, ssl, nginx

I've been trying for the past few days to get this to work correctly, but am coming up short.

(stackoverflow doesn't allow me to post more than two actual links -- disregard the back slashes)

The usual outcome is that `example\.net` and `www.example\.net` will redirect to http\s://example.net, while `http\s://www.example\.net` will not redirect to http\s://example.net, and another common circumstance is a message from the browser claiming the page is not redirecting properly.

What I'm trying to do is force absolutely all requests to go to http\s://example.net$request_uri.

```
            example\.net => http\s://example\.net
        www.example\.net => http\s://example\.net
https://www.example\.net => http\s://example\.net
```

nginx site config:

```
upstream backend {
  server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.example\.net example.net;
  return 301 http\s://example\.net$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl default_server;

  server_name example\.net;

  include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

  root /var/www/html/example;

  charset utf-8;
  index index.php;

  access_log /var/log/example-access.log;
  error_log /var/log/example-error.log;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php;
    index index.php;
  }

  location ~ .php {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass backend;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }

  location @extensionless-php {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
  }

  location /nginx_status {
    stub_status on;
    access_log off;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny all;
  }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create 2 blocks to handle the redirection to non-www HTTPS.
The final block is where you put your usual website's configurations/rules.

```
server {
    listen               80;
    server_name          www.example.net
                         example.net;
    return               301 https://example.net$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen               443 ssl;
    server_name          www.example.net;
    ssl_certificate      path/to/cert;
    ssl_certificate_key  path/to/key;
    return               301 https://example.net$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen               443 ssl;
    server_name          example.net;
    ssl_certificate      path/to/cert;
    ssl_certificate_key  path/to/key;

    # the rest goes here...
}
```